# Apache cant change listening port

Tags: apache, nginx

I am trying to install nginx as reverse frontend proxy to apache.

During this process I have to change the listening port for apache to e.g. 7070 instead of 80.

I went to the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and changed:

```
Listen 80
```

to

```
Listen 7070
```

I also added a virtualhost

```
NameVirtualHost *:7070
<VirtualHost *:7070>
//code
</VirtualHost>
```

at the end of it

However when i restart apache and nginx, nginx complains that port 80 is already in use and cannot be used

if i run

```
ss -plnt sport eq :80
```

i see lots of httpd processes/users.

What am i doing wrong, why is apache still on port 80?

If i do

```
sudo fuser -k 80/tcp
```

i can start nginx then, but then apache complains about the used port 80...

What am i doing wrong? :|

I am thankful for any help

Comment: Try killing the previous Apache process?

Comment: i did, as you can see in the second part of the question. However i can then start nginx or not apache. Both will never run at the same time

Comment: Strange case you have here... Try `cat /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf | grep 80` and inspect the output (you might have missed something). Once you're certain there's no trace of 80 port, **stop** both Nginx and Apache. Then start Nginx and Apache and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `NameVirtualHost` directive matching your virtualhosts somewhere in your config.
In your case, you'd need that, before the VirtualHosts declarations:

`NameVirtualHost *:7070`

As a matter of fact, you must have `NameVirtualHost *:80` somewhere already, just change the port there too.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add it to the question that I do have that as well.

Comment: Um, that's weird then